# Show sections based on value of Check box in jQuery (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I am trying to use jQuery to show section if a user selects a certain checkbox in a sharepoint form.  I have had success doing this with a button and with a simple checkbox with one value to show all from this blog post http://akanoongo.blogspot.com/2008/04/how-to-hide-fields-in-sharepoint-list.html, but am struggling with if they select multiple values.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/Libraries/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("nobr:contains('Desk Calendars')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').hide();
 $("nobr:contains('Calendar Refills')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').hide();
 $("nobr:contains('Spiral Bound')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').hide();
 $("nobr:contains('Wall Calendars')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').hide();
 $("nobr:contains('Misc. Calendars')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').hide();
 $("nobr:contains('Franklin Covey')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').hide();
 $("nobr:contains('Comments')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').hide();
 $("nobr:contains('Retention Policy')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').hide();

});

</script>
```

It would appear the value needs to be an if statement for contains VALUE not a click function.  I am not sure what to do with this though.

```
$("input[title$='ShowFields']").click(function()
```

Basically if they select Wall Calendars it should show jsut wall calendar but if they do Wall and desk, it should toggle them both.

Any guidance would be fantastic.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I change my answer based on your comment below

To do what you want I'll use the library I created that is called [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) (please load jQuery and SharepointPlus in your page). Then the JavaScript code would be something like:

```
// hide all the rows by default
$SP().formfields("Desk Calendars,Calendar Refills,Spiral Bound,Wall Calendars,Misc. Calendars,Franklin Covey,Comments,Retention Policy").row().hide();
// add a trigger for when you click a checkbox
$SP().formfields("Calendar Type").elem().on('click', function(event) {
  // the value of the checkbox is found with the "title" attribute from the parent
  // if it's checked, then we show the row, if it's not then we hide it
  $SP().formfields($(this).parent().attr("title")).row().toggle(this.checked)
})
```

Comment: Hey AymKdh, thanks for getting back to me.  I don't control the checkboxes directly beacuse it is sharepoint.  Here is an image of the form.  When you select the cooresponding check box, it needs to show that section only.  http://imgur.com/onlbUJu

Thoughts?